# How to toggle a div element between two images when click two submit buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How to toggle a div element between two images when click two submit buttons simultaneously? I have one div, 1st image should select when i click on the first submit button and then 2nd image while click 2nd button. How to do this either using jquery or js? Using with wordpress posts ,so little confused.

```
  <div class="first_image" id="1"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
  <div class="second_image" id="2"> 
    <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) :   MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?></div>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="" />
```

Comment: click two submit buttons simultaneously?

Comment: yes. I want the two submit button to click simultaneously.

Comment: If you have a form, what happen if you try to submit two time simultaniously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, id attributes must not start with a number. Instead use something like img1 to have valid HTML.

I suppose u want the first image to be shown by default and then toggle between the two images by clicking the buttons below.
So here is the jQuery approach:

```
<div class="first_image" id="img1">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<div class="second_image" id="img2" style="display: none;">
    <?php
    if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')):
        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');
    endif;
    ?>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn1" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting forms by accident
        $('#img1').show();
        $('#img2').hide();
    });
    $('#btn2').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting forms by accident
        $('#img1').hide();
        $('#img2').show();
    });
</script>
```

Further simplifications possible...

Comment: thanks..this is exactly what I want. between i need the first image to show by default before any of the buttton clicked. how to do that?

Comment: Oh sry... the first display: none; was just accidently. ;-)

Comment: how can I do it in a loop? I am using wordpress posts, so this should repeat with every posts in the loop. Now this is showing only for first post. Second post onwards ,will give only first image.can u help me?

Comment: @ Markus Kottländer how can I do it in a loop? I am using wordpress posts, so this should repeat with every posts in the loop. Now this is showing only for first post. Second post onwards ,will give only first image.can u help me?

Comment: I am not really a wordpress expert but this the related documentation i believe. http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 0):

First hide both the divs with `display:none`, then use the code below to show images 
on the click on any button:

```
jQuery('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    jQuery('#1').show();
    jQuery('#2').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hide both divs initially

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="" class="show_first_image" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="" class="show_second_image" />


$(document).ready(function(){
 $(':submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).attr('class') == 'show_first_image'){
   $('.first_image').show();
   $('.second_image').hide();
  }else{
   $('.second_image').show();
   $('.first_image').hide();
    }
  });

});
```